# Greenhouse (cold frame) side walls - footing question

Tags: concrete, footings

Planning a hoop house, or cold frame style greenhouse. I live in Nebraska, we get pretty consistent winds, not unusual to have 50 mph gusts.

I want set two parallel 3-4 ft tall rows of 4x4 posts, 4 ft apart. The 1-3/8" diameter "hoop" arches (made from chain link top-rail) will get secured to these posts every 4 feet.

I really don't want to bury the pressure treated 4x4's in: 
A) the heavy clay we have here
B) concrete

When they rot out, it would be difficult to replace if anchored by a 500 lb block of concrete.

Can I use a sonotube, then wet-set a 4x4 saddle and attach 4x4 to the saddle?

I read that concrete saddle's aren't really designed for wind-sheer (fencing) loads. Not sure if my hoop house would apply more of a wind sheer or downward force?

thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I went though the same issue. Better to use 1 7/8  galvanized pipe  4 feet long set in concrete (3 80 lb bags each hole) as a sleeve. Then 1 5/8 poles slide into the sleeve and are anchored with tek screws. Make sure your sleeve is 8 inches above ground of course so that you have something to fasten too. If you are useing 1 3/8 then you can find emt that will work as a sleeve as well. I have experienced 50mph winds with no problem on a 14x28 greenhouse 12 feet at the center in height.

As to sono tube... the fasten point at the saddle will be the weakest point of the structure as the horizontal wind load will be significant under high wind gusts. It will hold but I felt better with the set up above as the sleeve encased concrete and tek fastened would require the wall pole inserted into it to fail. At that point the structure would be toast regardless.